# Bias results of place autocomplete for selected city

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a drop-down menu for selecting city and an autocomplete text-box. I want only locations form selected city in drop-down.

```
function initAutocomplete() {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            (document.getElementById('auto')),{
                bounds: new google.maps.Circle({
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng( 18.520430,73.856744 ),
                    radius: 500
                }).getBounds(),
                types: ['establishment']
            });

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function(){});
}
```

I use above code for place autocomplete, but I want to dynamically pass longitude and latitude to this function. How can I do that? Please help me.
I'd like to have functionality like [swiggy.com](https://www.swiggy.com/) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When new city is selected and you have new lat,lng of that city, use this piece of code to update the bound of autocomplete widget with new value of `lat` and `lng`:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
bounds.extend(latLng);
autocomplete.setBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: @ntahoang How does this work conceptually? We are only providing a single 2D point. It just fetches whatever is closest?